# How do I calculate the power output of a 12 unit trickle charger for mobile phones?

Tags: power-supply, power, charger, cellphone

I'm trying to do some analysis on the power consumption of mobile phones, charged through a trickle charging unit. My scenario is as follows:

- 12x smartphones on a smartphone bay (wall).
- 1x Mains power point providing 230 V, 13 A
- 1x InVue security device with 12 micro USB charging points (note: this
  system secures the handsets to the smartphone wall and is alarmed,
  thus providing power for the alarm) This device provides a trickle
  charge to connected handsets.

The InVue device reads that it has 5 V and 6 A on the back. Is it safe to assume that this generates 30 W or uses 30 W?

Therefore, I am trying to find out if this device is fit for purpose. The 12 handsets should all be on, with full brightness, connected to Wi-Fi (no GSM usage) and run rolling video content. However, this is not the case as at least 1/3 handsets have no power.

I am making the assumption that the device is not fit for purpose, but I would like to understand how i calculate the output of the InVue device. Can anyone help?

Comment: You're going to have to provide links to information on the equipment you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The inVue part uses 30 W. That label is to tell what you need to provide. However USB through 2.0 requires 500 mA, so it should be able to provide 12 ports x 5 V x 0.5 A/port = 30 W. That makes me think it is either 1) mislabeled and it will draw more or 2) won't be able to provide full power to all 12 devices.

Comment: Also, my cellphone wall-type charger is rated to 0.7A. I would expect that for the phone to run (especially video) and charge simultaneously would be more than 0.5A. My phone complains if I charge and watch a video at the same time, no matter what charger is being used. The only way of really knowing is by having a knowledge of exactly how much power each phone needs to trickle charge and run video. but I doubt it's less than 0.5mA.

Comment: The **5 Volt** strongly suggest an *output* label. That sounds correct for 12 USB ports.